# How to make sharepoint 2010 web part page 508 compliance

Tags: visual-studio

I have a requirement to make the SharePoint 2010 list form and web part page section 508 compliance.
Could you please suggest to me a guide from MSDN or help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done but depends on EXACTLY what you are trying to do. If you want to create your own 508 compliant page, that's simply done through designer (using Div/Span over Table/TD). Once you have the layout as you need it you can simply add web part zones where you want them. However, the master page itself is not really 508 compliant - to accomplish this you may need to make changes there too.

Also, be aware many of the OOB parts display with tables (List views being one of them)!

Depending on the web parts you want to use, they can also be embedded into the page layout without using a Web Part Zone. This however makes them 'permanent' in the layout.

Which brings me to another question: when you say List form - which one exactly? Entry, Display? Your options here are many - you could easily start with the Content Query Web Part and use XSLT to properly render the list.

You can of course go a completely different route. I've done it using an embedded ASPX page (not tied to the SharePoint master) and have even hosted from another site using IFrame.

And as always true with SharePoint, yet a third way would be to create a custom web part that renders exactly what you want and you can use most SharePoint controls within it (this includes file upload, people picker and yes, web part zones).

So the questions;
1) What parts?
2) What List Form?

David Sterling
davidmsterling.blogspot.com
www.sterling-consulting.com
www.sharepoint-blog.com

Comment: Thanks for the thought full explanation.
It is a list data entry form and OOB part.
It needed some customization so that I hided the default form and added the custom New Data form. The form should be accessible for the screen reader users.
I like the idea of having my own custom web part. I can create a visual web part with the required controls as you have suggested.The master page less important.
Is the visual web part crated using VS210 accessible? As I have understood, SP web part page may not work, if this is a case what kind of aspx pages should I use?
Thanks again.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my response above? Once I have my custom web part ready, how do I provision it? Thanks again.

Comment: Provisiong a part is simple - as long as there are no permission issues (users have to be able to read the list - web parts run as the user), use a Sandbox solution. When built, these create WSP files - the WSP file is the web part - a sandbox one can be uploaded directly to the site.

Comment: David, thanks so much for your help. The webPart I have created is a visual web part as a farm solution because the user may not have a permission to the list. If I understood it correctly only a web part created as the sandbox can be deployed as WSP file? How do I use the WSP file or a web part in aspx page without using a web part zone? Sorry I am asking too much.